# Prometheus running in Kubernetes returns Empty reply from server and permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I'm fairly new to Kubernetes and Prometheus.  I've been following [these directions](https://devopscube.com/setup-prometheus-monitoring-on-kubernetes/) step by step.

I get to the section where I do port forwarding with:

```
kubectl port-forward <prometheus pod> 8080:9090 -n monitoring
```

At this point I should be able to go to http://localhost:8080 to get the Prometheus dashboard.  Instead I get:

```
# curl http://localhost:8080
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

And on the port forwarding process I get permission denied:

```
Handling connection for 8080
E0723 19:45:40.532119   18108 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 8080 -> 9090: error forwarding port 9090 to pod 3a04bc19fcc2f23f2c1b095df8ba472b455f91d6453a72575078b858df8d87a1, uid : exit status 1: 2021/07/23 19:45:40 socat[22259] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:9090, 16): Permission denied
```

If I look at the prometheus pod logs, it looks happy:

```
level=info ts=2021-07-23T19:14:38.691Z caller=kubernetes.go:282 component="discovery manager scrape" discovery=kubernetes msg="Using pod service account via in-cluster config"
level=info ts=2021-07-23T19:14:38.692Z caller=kubernetes.go:282 component="discovery manager scrape" discovery=kubernetes msg="Using pod service account via in-cluster config"
level=info ts=2021-07-23T19:14:38.693Z caller=kubernetes.go:282 component="discovery manager scrape" discovery=kubernetes msg="Using pod service account via in-cluster config"
level=info ts=2021-07-23T19:14:38.695Z caller=main.go:1012 msg="Completed loading of configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml totalDuration=10.027206ms remote_storage=8.294µs web_handler=307ns query_engine=2.796µs scrape=801.585µs scrape_sd=3.181796ms notify=23.042µs notify_sd=10.213µs rules=550.517µs
level=info ts=2021-07-23T19:14:38.695Z caller=main.go:796 msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."
```

I tried google first and haven't found any matches that includes all the above.

I'm not sure if it matters running on localhost, but I do have the firewall open on that port

```
# iptables -xvn -L|grep 8080
      21     1166 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
```

I suspect that the issue might have something to do with the root user running the Prometheus pod.  If I `kubectl exec` in to the Prometheus pod, everything is owned and running as root also.  I've looked at manual installations of Prometheus and those instructions always have you create a Prometheus user and group and run as the Prometheus user.  But the Prometheus container is coming right from dockerhub so I don't know how I would change the user inside the docker image.  But this is just all a guess at this point and have no idea really.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is a Centos 7 server running Kubernetes 1.18.
Prometheus is the latest dockerhub image `prom/prometheus`

TIA

-Jon

Comment: 1. what happens if you curl http://0.0.0.0:8080

Comment: 2. what happens if you run port-forward unders the sudo?

Comment: 3. Just tested quickly on GCP instance(used ubuntu, not centos. k8s 1.21)on  newly created cluster - after  creating namespace, config-map.yaml, clusterRole.yaml and prometheus-deployment.yaml am can successfully do `kubectl port-forward prometheus-deployment-599bbd9457-pkxqk 8089:9090 -n monitoring` ans see the result `curl http://localhost:8089` --> <a href="/graph">Found</a>.

Comment: 4. have you tried kubectl port-forward --address localhost,0.0.0.0 pod/<prometheus pod> 8080:9090 ?

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.  Sorry for the late response as I was out yesterday.  

1. If I try to curl to 0.0.0.0:8080, I get the same as using localhost.

2. I did the port forward as root

3.  Yeah, I keep getting permission denied.  I'm wondering if I should try an older version of premetheus as a test.

4. I'll give that a shot next

Comment: you know, I also today reproduced your case on latest minikube on windows... - everything works like a charm with latest prometheus, and even more - it works with localhost:8080 as expected without throwing ANY errors during port-forwarding.  So either 1)centos configuration(can you try for test other?); 2)can you for test use latest kubernetes or minikube?

Comment: your cni is configured? what you use?

Comment: Thanks for the additional help.  I don't have the option of trying anything other than centos at this time.  The product that we're developing is on Centos so I have to try and get prometheus working on Centos to monitor the product performance.  I actually did get the prometheus binary installed on a Ubuntu server and pointed at the URL on the centos server and got that to work.  But ultimately, I need to get Prometheus to run on the same server as the product we're developing.  It has to be a weird edge case issue since there are not any google results for this issue.

Comment: What is CNI?  Are you talking about networking?  I can run netstat and see that the port is listening okay.

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/cni-kubernetes

Comment: can you provide steps how you initially  installed and configured kubernetes in centos? Just steps what you have done and  tool you used? kubeadm, minkube, etc.. CNI important  part of cluster. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network

Comment: Ah, I see.  It was actually setup by our infrastructure team so I had no part in deploying K8S.  I have root access to do what I need, but I didn't set it up.  I was able to deploy other pods okay like metrics-server and kube-state-metrics.  I now what to install prometheus to monitor the /metrics URL created by kube-state-metrics. So maybe Prometheus needs something extra. I'll contact our infra team for clarification.  Maybe there is something disabled that I need.

Comment: And I will also double check from my side and maybe try to reproduce in centos. And you please check with it department the way it was installed

Comment: Fixed it!  It has to do with centos being an SELinux-hardened system.
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Permissive_versus_enforcing

Once I ran "setenforce 0" and redid the port-forward, it started working.

Thanks for all your time you spent helping.  Much appreciated.

Comment: oh yeah, bravo! for sure, by default during k8s installation selinux should be set to permissive mode and swap should be disabled unless you have other strong project security requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by switching centos to [permissive mode](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Permissive_versus_enforcing).

During kubernetes installation on SELinux-enabled systems you should disable  it so all containers can access host filesystem.

Please note that disabling SELinux by `setenforce 0` is only a temporary solution (as like turning off swap by `swapoff -a`

To completely disable them:

- SELinux: edit `/etc/selinux/config` and set `SELINUX=disabled`
- Swap: edit `/etc/fstab` and comment(#) swap entry